# Won't have to say or Won't be saying?

Tags: grammaticality

I've written this thing, and part of it's talking about something that will happen in the future.

(For when people will have to say, "She's died." They won't have to say, "She's died in vain.")

The sentence:"They won't have to say," I can't decide whether it's correct or I should use the future continuous tense, and say, "They won't be saying."

So, do I have to use the future continuous tense here?

(Edited: No more answers needed for this question. Thank you!)

Comment: Sorry, Hajar, there is not enough information there for a useful Comment, let alone an answer.

In the conext of what you might be asking, 'For when people will have to say, "She's died." They won't have to say, "She's died in vain" ' makes too little sense to comment on.

Comment: I understand why it does too little sense to you. It's part of a poem I was trying to write, then. And I sometimes get confused when I talk about something that will happen in the future for a period of time. So I wasn't sure what kind of future tense that I should've used in it. Thank you. :)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Here's the poem: I don’t remember how to write./
I keep forgetting how to paint./
Life has become a burden, that/
No one knows for how long/
I have to bear./

A voice in my head shouts,/
”Other people have it worse. Never/
Hear you complain, again.”/

As if this will make me stronger./
As if this will dull the pain./

Give me back my words./
Or teach me how to paint, again./

And perhaps, I’ll depict a road /
To serenity, or write a poem/
That will ease my pain./

For when people will have to say,/
”She’s died.” They won’t have to say,/
”She’s died in vain.”

Comment: To how many people fluent in both English and your own language have you showed this, please? Sorry to say the only part of your poem I do understand is that final ' ”She’s died.” They won’t have to say,
”She’s died in vain.” ' and the way you wrote about even that doesn't really work in English punctuation…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  I showed it only to some people fluent in English on Tumblr. But would you, please, tell me why that sentence doesn't work in English punctuation? How should it be written to be correct? Thank you. :)

Comment: How should what be written, please? Your poem had 18 lines…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The last line. What's its correct punctuation?

Comment: Sorry, Hajar, if that's what you're asking about it's pure literary criticism, or personal choice. Even so, your last line was "She’s died in vain", was it not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It's fine! I really appreciate any kind of help. And yes, it was. But I really meant that last part, starting from "For when people will have to say..." To the end. Does that sound grammatically weird to native speakers? Thank you so much for your time, by the way.

Comment: First, please recognise the difference between "The last line" and "that last part, starting from "For when people will have to say..." To the end"

Then, try to stick to one clear thing, at worst.

Nevertheless, you are asking for literary criticism or personal choice, neither of which is allowed on ELU.

Why would it be difficult for you to find a WWW forum dealing with  literary criticism, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It would not be difficult for me to find a www forum, at all! And I wasn't asking for literary criticism or personal choice. I was asking about something relatable to the use of two different future tenses. Which I now understand, btw.  But you said that the original question did too little sense to you. And when I showed you the context to make things clearer, you said that only the last part you could understand and that even the way I wrote it didn't really work in English punctuation. So that didn't sound like a personal choice to me. That's all.

Comment: Hajar, please be a lot more realistic. Either explain everything, or drop the whole lot but please don't pretend you weren't warned. What you said made almost no sense and that's really there is to it.

Re-phrase what you said and it might become the most eloquent passage ever written… but until you re-phrase it, please accept the simple fact; it made no sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using "won't" rather than "will not" and in a negative sense (possible source of confusion) still expresses the same future.  It still expresses the same tense - which is the future perfect tense - "They will not have to say". This is not the future perfect continuous tense - "They will not have to be saying (ongoing - from that point on forward or until some point in the further future). However, depending on the exact meaning you actually want to convey, you could use either future expression - just be clear on the subtle differences between them.  Here is a link that visually shows the differences with diagrams.  The visual diagrams helped to make the choices clearer to me.

https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/future_tense.htm

Comment: Did you notice that using "won't" rather than "will not" had hardly anything to do with the OQ's point?